# for all $a$ and $b$, satisfies $x^a y^b=\frac{3}{4}^{a-b} \text{and } x^b y^a=\frac{3}{4}^{b-a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the only ordered pair of numbers $(x,y)$ which, for all $a$ and $b$, satisfies

$$x^a y^b=\left(\frac34\right)^{a-b} \text{and } x^b y^a=\left(\frac34\right)^{b-a}$$

I started off with the trivial cases, $a=0$ and $b=0$ and you get $1=1$ on both sides, so that works.

I can't seem to find anymore cases. Any ideas?

Comment: is it $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{b-a}$ or $\frac{3^{b-a}}{4}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I presume $\left(\frac34\right)^{b-a}$ as the OP is saying $a=b=0$ gave him$1=1$ on both sides.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner my fault, i shall fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(x^ay^b\right)\times\left(x^by^a\right)=\left(\frac34\right)^{a-b}\times\left(\frac34\right)^{b-a}$$
$$(xy)^{a+b}=1$$
$$xy=1$$
$$x^ax^{-b}=\left(\frac34\right)^{a-b}$$
$$\therefore x=\frac34,\space y=\frac43$$

Answer (score 1):

By inspection,

$$
x = x^1y^0 = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{1-0} = \frac{3}{4}
$$

and

$$
y = x^0y^1 = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{0-1} = \frac{4}{3}
$$

Note that this only suffices to identify $x$ and $y$ provided the condition stated actually holds; it does not prove that this $x$ and $y$ work for all $a$ and $b$, so if you need to demonstrate that, there is more work to be done (though it is straightforward).